# how to extend lifetime of a meteor login token?

Tags: authentication, meteor

I have a meteor app that seems to force a logout after 24 hours. 
Our app (in beta) is using a "guest login" process where we create accounts on the fly, so i want to actually have an indefinite token lifetime. 
Is there a way to extend the lifetime of these tokens?

```
Error logging in with token: Error: You've been logged out by the server. Please log in again. [403]
update failed: Access denied
```

Our guest login looks something like this:

```
postCreateUser = (username, password) ->
  dclib.clog("login", "created", username)
  Meteor.loginWithPassword username, password, ->
    # FIXME? could this be in onCreateUser server side?
    Meteor.call "createPersonalRoomIfNone"


if Meteor.isClient
  Meteor.startup ->
    unless Meteor.userId()
      Meteor.call "getLastUserIndex", (err,index)->
        if err
          throw err
        console.log("creating guest user", index)
        username = "Guest #{index}"
        password = Random.id()
        Accounts.createUser
          username: username
          email: ""
          password: password
          role: "guest"
        , -> postCreateUser(username, password)
```

Comment: I bet you could update `window.localStorage['Meteor.loginTokenExpires']` as well as rehash the token and set the `hashedToken` and `when` in the database. There is also `Accounts.config.loginExpirationInDays` that you can set to days or null for forever, but this applies to all accounts. I'm interested to see what other, better, solutions are provided.

Answer (score 0):

this does it i hope!

```
# prevent users getting logged out
# http://devdocs.io/meteor/index#accounts_config
Accounts.config ({loginExpirationInDays: null})
```